# How to show colored emoji from custom font on Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, emoji

I'd like to use [Twemoji font](https://github.com/eosrei/twemoji-color-font) in my Flutter app. I installed this font. But when I try to use it in `TextSpan`, I see monochromatic emoji instead of colored. How to fix it?

[image: Result]

My code:

```
RichText(
    text: TextSpan(
      children: <TextSpan>[
        TextSpan(text: "Some text ", style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
          fontSize: 24,
          color: Colors.black,
        )),
        TextSpan(text: "", style: TextStyle(
          fontFamily: "TwitterColorEmoji",
          fontSize: 24,
        )),
      ]
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it, [Twemoji font](https://github.com/eosrei/twemoji-color-font) works in all operating system but will currently only show color emoji in Firefox, Thunderbird, Photoshop CC 2017+, and Windows Edge V38.14393+. This is not a limitation of the font, but of the operating systems and applications.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to add my code. I've already used `RichText` widget.

Comment: Does it work now?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Read my comment on answer below.

Comment: The issue was mentioned in the github repository of the font

Answer (score 3):

As of Flutter 3.10 a new parameter `useColorEmoji` can now be passed when initializing the engine on web.

See: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/119536#issuecomment-1513309144

Comment: Thanks! I could not find a good solution anywhere, but then found your answer, and it was exactly the kind of solution I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

As has been said, due to limits of operation system and applications, this font won't show colored emojies.

I think the best altenative way to show colored emojies is using `WidgetSpan` with `SvgPicture` like in code below:

```
      RichText(
        text: TextSpan(
          children: [
            TextSpan(
              text: "Some text ",
              style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                fontSize: 24,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
            WidgetSpan(
              child: SvgPicture.asset("assets/emojies/confused-face.svg"),
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```