# Flutter shows black & white emoji, but the same works fine on terminal just like expected

Tags: flutter, dart, utf-8, emoji

Flutter:

[image]

Terminal:
[image]

How can resolve this?

```dart
  fetchFeed() async {
    try {
      final response = await http.get(
        Uri.parse('http://localhost:8080/'),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'},
      );
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final List<dynamic> body = json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
        setState(() {
          feedData =
              body.map((dynamic item) => FeedItem.fromJson(item)).toList();
        });
      }
      print(response.body);
      print(response.statusCode);
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error: $e");
    }
  }
```

Comment: This might be relevant https://stackoverflow.com/a/70615778/13625293